# How to replace the negative values of a C# winforms datagridview with N/A

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a c# winforms datagridview, it is filled with the data that has been fetched from the database. Now I want the negative values of the grid to be replaced with N/A for all the columns in it.

Comment: Post the code you have written

Comment: Why not go through all cells and compare their values with 0? If it is less than 0, you just change it to "N/A".

Comment: I can't do this as it will have more than 10 columns and 500 rows in the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe to `CellFormatting` event. In the event handler, check if the value is negative then set the value to N/A. In the sample column, I have done for first column. One catch here is that the new value should be of the type specified by the cell `FormattedValueType` property.

Sample code:

```
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.Value != null)
        {
            int val;
            if (int.TryParse(e.Value.ToString(), out val) && val < 0)
            {
                e.Value = "N/A";
                e.FormattingApplied = true;
            }
        }
    }
```